# iOS: Adding annotation array derived from fetched results controller not showing

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, mkmapview

I basically have a view where you can switch between a table and a map view. In the table as in the map you can add a location. And it should be displayed directly on the map. Now I have a fetched results controller controlling the coredata part. To speed things up I want to always keep the annotations up to date in an array, so the map only needs to draw the annotations directly onto the map and not create them once again. But somehow nothing is displayed:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *mapPins;

- (IBAction)switchTableMapClicked:(id)sender {
    if(self.mapViewVisible){
        self.mapViewVisible = NO;
        self.mapView.hidden = YES;
        self.tableView.hidden = NO;
    } else {
        self.mapViewVisible = YES;
        self.mapView.hidden = NO;
        self.tableView.hidden = YES;
        [self initializePins];
    }
}

- (void)initializePins
{
    NSMutableArray *tempoPins;
    self.mapPins = nil;

    for (PointOfInterest *location in self.frc.fetchedObjects) {
        MKPointAnnotation *annotation = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
        [annotation setCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([location.latitude doubleValue], [location.longitude doubleValue])];
        [annotation setTitle:@"Entry"];
        [tempoPins addObject:annotation];
    }

    self.mapPins = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:tempoPins];
    [self.mapView addAnnotations:self.mapPins];
}
```

Comment: Didn't you forget to alloc+init tempoPins?

Comment: lol stupid me, just too tired I guess :-) JEP that's it. Thx Anna!